# How to access 'Object' portion of JSON using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I used console.table(someData) to output the object shows in the attaches image.

I used the following code to get the data:

```
var someData = GetJson('someurlthatreturnsjson');

function GetJson(Url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

I tried:

```
var x = someData.readyState;  // 1 was returned as expected.
var y = someData.Object;      // undefined.
...so...
var z = someData.Object.responseJSON; // also undefined?
```

So how would I access elements within the Object portion of this json? Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: try `var z = someData.responseJSON;`

Comment: Why are you doing `.Object`? There's no such property in the object you've logged.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen No that doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi Well, the output of the original JSON shows 'Object' at the same level as the 'readyState' property, which I can access, so I figured it would be accessed the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you `return` the `$.ajax()` call from `getJSON()`, the `someData` variable will contain the [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) containing the reference to the AJAX call.

To retrieve the response from that call from the Deferred object you can use any of the methods outlined in the documentation I linked to. I would suggest using `then()` in this case, as the handler function you define will receive the response as the first argument to the function, like this:

```
var someData = GetJson('someurlthatreturnsjson').then(response => {
  // do something with the response here...

  console.dir(response);
});

function GetJson(Url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: Url,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, I thought I was getting away with something. 

So the 'someData' variable is pretty much useless.

Comment: In the example above, yes. However you could still store the reference to the deferred object and pass it to another function to be handled.

Comment: If I did store this object at what point does the it become... more accessible. When and how could I use the data within the 'Object' portion?

Comment: You would always have to call then() (or any other method for accessing the response) to retrieve the response data